# Set Aut F of all field automorphisms is a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

This question is from my abstract algebra course.

Instructor told us to prove this by ourselves.

> The set Aut F of all field automorphisms $F \to F$ forms a group under the operation of composition of functions.

I have problem in proving how inverse of a function $\sigma$ exists. Which result I should use?

Can you please tell how to prove that inverse exists.

Comment: This result is not true for all fields $F$. There has to be some additional quantifications. For example, the Frobenius endomorphism will not be invertible in a non-perfect field.

Comment: Usually one denotes all automorphism with $\operatorname{Aut}$, are you sure it's supposed to be just homomorphisms? (One would rather write $\operatorname{End}{F}$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $ \sigma \in Aut F$ then $\exists \sigma^{-1} : F \rightarrow F$ which is a bijection.
We have
$$\forall (y_1, y_2) \in F^2 \quad y_1+y_2 = \sigma(\sigma^{-1}(y_1)) + \sigma(\sigma^{-1}(y_2)) = \sigma(\sigma^{-1}(y_1) + \sigma^{-1}(y_2)).$$
Hence
$$\sigma^{-1}(y_1+y_2) = \sigma^{-1}(y_1) + \sigma^{-1}(y_2).$$
And
$\forall \lambda \in \mathbb R \quad \forall y \in F$ we have
$$\lambda y= \lambda\sigma\sigma^{-1}(y) =\sigma(\lambda\sigma^{-1}(y)).$$
Then
$$\sigma^{-1}(\lambda y)=\lambda \sigma^{-1}(y).$$

Answer (score 4):

This is not always the case. For example the mapping
$$
\sigma:\frac{a(t)}{b(t)}\mapsto \frac{a(t^2)}{b(t^2)}
$$
is a non-surjective homomorphism from the field $F=\Bbb{R}(t)$ of rational functions to itself. Here $a(t),b(t)$ are arbitrary polynomials.

---

However, the following general facts do allow us to conclude this in many special cases:

- A homomorphism of fields necessarily has a trivial kernel, and is thus always injective.
- A homomorphism of fields is always linear over the prime field $k$. Therefore by rank-nullity an injective homomorphism is always surjective, if $[F:k]<\infty$.

So if $F$ is a finite extension of $\Bbb{Q}$ or $\Bbb{F}_p$ for some prime number $p$, the claim holds automatically.

It is true in some other cases as well. For example in the cases [$F=\Bbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/456266/11619) and [$F=\Bbb{Q}_p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/449465/11619) (= the field of $p$-adic numbers) simply because in those cases the identity mapping is the only automorphism.

Comment: It was supposed to be automorphism instead of homomorphism but please don't delete your answer . it is quite helpful and informative . I am ashamed of my mistake and I am sorry!!

Comment: I think the homomorphism you mentioned is onto. Can you give a proof of it how its not onto

Comment: @User The rational function $t\in F$ is not in the image. It is impossible to find polynomials $a(t),b(t)$, $b(t)\neq0$, such that $t=a(t^2)/b(t^2)$. For that to happen we need the polynomial identity
$$t b(t^2)= a(t^2),$$ but on the left we have only odd degree terms and on the right we only have even degree terms, so all the term must vanish contradicting $b(t)\neq0$.