# Just a query on continuity

Tags: real-analysis, ring-theory, proof-verification

I was told to find $\def\R{\mathbb R}$$\R$ to $\R$ ring homomorphisms.

I have proved that if $x>0$ then $f(x)>0$ 
After this it follows $f$ is a strictly increasing function.

Then I attempted to prove continuity for all points in $\R$.

I have in this following way. Please check if it is correct.
Let $c$ be an arbitrary point of $\R$.
For any $\def\e{\epsilon}\e>0$, by the Archimedean property there exits $n\in\mathbb N$, natural number such that $1/n<\e$ for $|x-c|<1/n$ we have 
$-1/n <x-c<1/n$ hence $f(-1/n)<f(x-c)<f(1/n)$ and therefore $-1/nf(1)<f(x-c)<1/nf(1)$

$|f(x)-f(c)|< \frac{1}{n}f(1) <\epsilon f(1) $ 
 I will conclude $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to c} f(x)=f(c)$;

is my proof correct? You can provide an independent proof too!

Have a look at this :[Ring homomorphisms $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411459/ring-homomorphisms-mathbbr-to-mathbbr)

Answer (score 1):

You've proven that $f$ is increasing. The next step is to note that $f$ has to fix the rationals. Now suppose that there is some (obviously irrational) $x$ such that $x \neq f(x)$. Then there must be some rational $q$ between $x$ and $f(x)$. Now what happens if $x < q$? Or if $x > q$?