# Prove this function is the identity

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove if $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ with the properties $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$, $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$ for any $x,y\in \mathbb R$ and $f(1)=1$  is $1-1$.

I'm solving this question proving $f$ is the identity map. In order to do this I've already prove this for the natural, integers and rational numbers, but I couldn't prove it for the real numbers because I don't have the continuity assumption.

Thanks

Comment: By 1 - 1 do you mean 'one to one' or injective?

Comment: Also $f$ need not be the identity function, it could just as well map all real numbers to 0. Which is not an injective function.

Comment: @mb7744 injective

Comment: @mb7744 I'm sorry, see my edit please

Comment: I fear that without continuity at least at a point you can find, using a Hamel basis, ''wilde'' functions that has son given values (e.g. $0$) for all irrational numbers. You can look at: **J. Aczél, Lectures on functional equations and applications par. 2.1 and 2-2**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a comment if I had enough reputation. Your assumptions make $f$ into a *ring homomorphism* $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Thus this question is answered in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411459/ring-homomorphisms-mathbbr-to-mathbbr). (In short, after you have shown that the restriction to $\mathbb{Q}$ is the identity, you can use the ordering and density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ to show that $f$ is continuous.)

**EDIT** (in reply to a comment)
Let's skip continuity and take advantage of the ordering. We wish to show that 
$$ x < y \Rightarrow f(x) < f(y),$$
because with this we can 'squeeze' the values of the function in irrational points to the identity without explicitly saying the word 'continuous'.
Note that to show our claim it suffices to prove that for all $x$ and $y$ we have
$$ \frac{y}{x} > 0 \Rightarrow \frac{f(y)}{f(x)} > 0,$$
and since by assumption $f(ab) = f(a)f(b)$ it is sufficient to show that
$z > 0 $ implies $f(z) > 0$. But this is not hard, because if $ z > 0$, then for some $w > 0$ it holds that $z = w^2$, and so
$$f(z) = f(w w) = f(w) f(w) = f(w)^2 > 0.$$
Thus $f$ is order preserving, and if it is the identity on the rationals, it must be an identity map on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The problem is I would like to show this question to my students who don't see what is continuity yet.

Comment: @user42912, my overlong comment got turned into an edit of the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, with it I could prove the injectivity. However I still think we have to use continuity somehow to prove this map is the identity. I couldn't prove this claim without continuity:  "$f$ is order preserving, and if it is the identity on the rationals, it must be an identity map on all of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Np :) ...I think we can still tiptoe around that part and hide the continuity. To show that $f$ is identity I'd argue the following; suppose we had a point $z \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q} $ for which $f(z) \neq z$. If $f(z) > z$, take a rational number $q$ such that $z < q < f(z)$. Since $f$ preserves order and $z < q$, we have $f(z) < f(q)$ and this is a contradiction with the selection of $q$. A similar argument shows that also $f(z) < z$ is impossible.

Comment: Great!!! thank you very much again!