# Describe all ring homomorphisms from $\mathbb{R}[T] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}[T]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

One of the problems in a problem set I was given as homework in my Algebra course proposes the next problem:

> Describe all ring homomorphisms $\mathbb{R}[T] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}[T]$. Which of them are isomorphisms?

I would like some suggestions towards the right direction, not the answer to the problem.

This is what I've got so far:

Given a ring homomorphism $f:\mathbb{R}[T] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}[T]$:

Given an arbitrary polinomial $p(T) = a_{0} + a_{1}T + \ldots + a_nT^n$ we have that $f(p) = f(a_0) + f(a_1)f(T) + \ldots + f(a_n)f(T)^n$. So we get that $f$ is completely determined by the values it assumes on $\mathbb{R}$ and $f(T)$.

So this problem may now be separated in two:

1. Classifying all homomorphisms of the form $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}[T]$
2. Classifying all possible values $f(T)$

With respect to (1):

**Conjecture**
The only ring homomorphism is $f(x)=x$ (we put as a condition that f(1) = 1, on the definition the professor gave us, so that discards $f(x)=0$)

I've shown by induction that $f(n) = n, ~\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $f(m) = m, ~\forall m\in \mathbb{Z}$, then $f(q) = q, ~\forall q\in \mathbb{Q}$ but I
am having problems showing that $f(\alpha) = \alpha, ~\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{Q}'$ because I don't really know if $f(\alpha) \in \mathbb{R}$.

If I knew that $f(\mathbb{R}) \subset \mathbb{R}$ then I could do something like $f(\alpha) = f(\sqrt{\alpha})^2 > 0$ if $\alpha > 0$. And this would help me prove that $f(\beta) = \beta$ for all irrationals too. The only problem is that, what happens if say, $f(\alpha) = T$. Then $>$ would make no sense.

I think I solved this problem but I am not sure, maybe here is where you guys can help me a little.

If we suppose that $f(\alpha)$ is a polynomial with degree $n$, we can then compute $f(\alpha^\frac{1}{n+1}) = f(\alpha)^\frac{1}{n+1}$ and that would be in $\mathbb{R}[T]$ only if the degree, $n$, of $f(\alpha)$ were $0$ thus proving that indeed $f(\alpha) \in \mathbb{R}$.

Is there any mistake or an easier way? Or is there any usefull comment anyone wants to make that could help me out. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can use the fact that every element of $\mathbb{R}^*$ is invertible in $\mathbb{R}[T]$, so its image by $f$ must be invertible in $\mathbb{R}[T]$.

Comment: It looks like your attempt is very good, and I don't think that there's a swifter way to approach it. You're right in that $\mathbb{R}$ maps to $\mathbb{R}$, I would use the fact that units map to units (which is not so hard to prove) and that the only units of $\mathbb{R}[T]$ are the non-zero constants.

Comment: the argument is that a ring homomorphism $\mathbb{R}[T] \to \mathbb{R}[T]$ has to be a ring (field) homomorphism $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only Homomorphism on $\mathbb R$ that fixes $1$, is the identity map. For the proof you can see [Ring homomorphisms $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ .](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/411475)
Since $f$ is a homomorphism that fixes $1$, image of every invertible elements in $\mathbb R[T]$ should be invertible, and we should have $f_{|\mathbb R}=Id_{\mathbb R}$ .

$f$ completely determined by the image of $T$, and so

$f(a_0+a_1T+...+a_nT)=a_0+a_1(p(T))+...+a_n(p(T))^n$ where $p(T)=f(T)$.

At last $f$ is isomorphism iff $f(T)=aT+b$

Answer (score 0):

**(Big) hint:** Show that a (unital) ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{R}[T]$ to any other unital ring $A$ is completely determined by the image of $T$.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: I'm not downvoter, but I think your answer is very summary and ignored the fact that $f$ should be identity on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @2000 I agree it is terse, but that's why I dubbed it a "hint". Also, the fact that it is the identity on $\mathbb{R}$ is a direct consequence to the fact that the morphism is a morphism of unital rings...