# Question about ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/411475/121097) by Hagen von Eitzen they said that, we can conclude that, $f(x)=xf(1)$ also holds for $x\in\mathbb{Q}$. How to show this?

I just tried like this: $f(q\frac{1}{q})=f(1)$ that implies $f(q)f(\frac{1}{q})=f(1)$ that implise $qf(1)f(\frac{1}{q})=f(1)$ But from this we can't conclude that, $f(1/q)=\frac{1}{q}f(1)$ unless **we must already have** $f(1)=1$.

Comment: $f(1)=f(1^2)=f(1)f(1)$, so $f(1)$ equals 0 or 1.

Comment: @AndrewHubery so when $f(1)=0$ then $f(x)=f(x1)=f(x)f(1)=f(x)0=0=xf(1)$ and hence $f(x)=xf(1)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449404/is-an-automorphism-of-the-field-of-real-numbers-the-identity-map

Comment: If $f : G \to H$ is a group homomorphism (use additive notation on both $G$ and $H$), then $f(nx) = nf(x)$ for all $n \in \mathbb Z$ and $x \in G$. In your case, if $m, n \in \mathbb Z$ and $n \neq 0$, then $nf(m/n) = f(n(m/n)) = f(m) = mf(1)$, so dividing both sides by $n$ we get…